# Need help in proving a result rellated to small o notation in number theory

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am self studying a research paper in number theory  I am unable to think  how to prove two identities involving  small o notation.

Unfortunately, I am unable to think about the way to derive them

> Assume r= r(a) as an integer
>
> Then , we have log(r) +$\frac{a-r}{a+1} log(2)$ = (1+o(1) ) log(a)

and
 1+log(2)+$\frac{2r+1}{a+1} log(r+1) $ = 1+ log(2) + o(1).

Can someone please help in deriving one of the identities.
(These is exactly the last page of the paper) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the second in a power series in $a$ centered at $\infty$ (or equivalently, replacing $a$ with $1/b$ and expanding in a power series in $b$ centered at $0$),
$$  1 + \ln 2 + \frac{2r+1}{a+1}\ln(r+1) = 1 + \ln 2 + \frac{(2r+1)\ln(r+1)}{a} + \frac{-(2r+1)\ln(r+1)}{a^2} + \cdots  $$
(This is literally an application of the geometric series formula 
$$  \frac{c}{1-r} = c + cr + cr^2, \quad |r|<1  \text{,}  $$
with $r = 1/a$ and the constant term $0$ because in the limit as $a \rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{c}{a+1} \rightarrow 0$.)

Then every term on the right is decreasing in $a$, so the sum is decreasing in $a$ (i.e., is bounded by a constant on any interval $[N,\infty)$).  Therefore, the right hand side is $1 + \ln 2 + o(1)$.

Comment: I am sorry but I am unable to understand why constant term is 0 . Also, it is to be proved o(1) not O(1) . How the last paragraph prove it to be o(1)? Your argument used in Last paragraph proves it to be O(1) !!

Comment: You are expanding around $a = \infty$.  What do you think happens to $2r+1$ when you divide it by $\infty + 1$?  You get $0$.

Comment: @Dxdxdade : The o or O in your Question does not have a readily resolvable size; it is the same size as $1$ and $2$, just as is $O(1,2)$.  You should use math formatting if you want your text to be less ambiguous.  Also, you are incorrect.  I have shown for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $N$ such that the remainder of the series is bounded by $\varepsilon \cdot 1$, as required for little $o$.  $1/a$ **is** $o(1)$, why do you believe it is not?

Comment: I was confused!! You are right.

Comment: , I tried proving 1st equation,  unfortunately I am unable to prove it using the method you used to prove (2)  . I got log (2r) +o(1)  instead of getting log(a) +o(1)  !! . It is my humble request if you can tell how it would be done.